# is this matrix invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've got this question where $a$ is constant placed in a matrix
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}1&1&a\\0&a&0\\1&0&1\end{matrix}\right]$$
is the matrix $A$ invertible? what is the inverse of $A$? how can I find what a is?

Comment: Solve the equation $\det A=0$ and pick the other values. For such values, calculate $A^{-1}$ with the "cofactor formula" (which I like to call "the formula" because, afaik, it's the only one).

Comment: If a = 0 or 1 then not. Try to reduce it or check its determinant

Comment: Ok, thanks ....

Comment: Hint: write the condition for a matrix to be invertible, in terms of its elements.

Comment: @Cerkal No need to check the determinant in this case, because it is a polynomial of degree $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. The determinant of $A$ is $a(1-a)$, so the matrix $A$ is invertible iff $a\not\in \{0,1\}$. For those values,
$$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{a(1-a)}\left[\begin{matrix}a&-1&-a^2\\*&*&*\\*&*&*\end{matrix}\right].$$
In order to find the remaining elements take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_3_.C3.97_3_matrices).